# Navigation Back Button Taking back to wrong view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have three screen as below, now i go from the list of hotels to their detail view and from their to the ratings page, i perform the ratings and come back to detail page with ratings added, but now however , if i were to use the back button the navigation takes me back to ratings page instead of main page with hotels list , can any one please suggest how to avoid it ...

A->B->C but when coming back C->B but now B->C instead of B->A

[image]

[image]

[image]

SOLVED

So here is the mistake i was making

```
let backimage = UIImage(named: "back")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backimage
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backimage
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBackButton))
```

I was trying to hit the navigation bar back button item and make it do the work, it would reset back to default, what i need was to target navigationItem and not navigationcontroller, which i did and now from my handler it goes to root controller like below

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleBackButton))

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBackButton))






   @objc func handleBackButton() {
      
           _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
       }
```

Comment: every push your controller?

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: false), i use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Following scenarios code u can use:

1) C->B or B->A
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
2) C->A
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigationController, to pop back manually you have to use.

```
    _=self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

For pop to a specific view controller you have to use

```
     self.navigationController?.popToViewController(yourViewController, animated: true)
```

But before this you have to confirm that the navigation array contains the view controller to pop.

But this is not required for default navigation back button.

I think your issue is with pushing view controller to navigationController.
Please refer the codes for push:

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController!, animated: true)
```

Note: pop will not work with presentViewController